# "Missing template" error in Omniauth (ruby-on-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm using OmniAuth for Facebook Authentication, and I keep getting this error:

```
Missing template authentications/index with
{:handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :builder, :rxml, :erb], 
 :locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths
```

The view file is present in the app directory, but is apparently not seen.

Comment: I have the template present in the authentications view as index.html.erb

Comment: Can you paste your `config/routes.rb` and the authentications controller? ty

Answer (score 0):

add

```
resources :authentications
```

to your config/routes.rb file